# Computing network kernel density estimate with Python

Tags: python, spatial-statistics, network, kernel-density

I'm using Python to do a project that requires me getting a network-based kernel density estimate to find areas with the densest concentration of car crashes. I have a road and car crash shapefile ready to go. However, I can't seem to find any packages or workflows online on how to do it with Python, only R. Does anyone know about any resources that could help?

Comment: When I googled kernel density estimation using Python, the first package shown is [scikit-learn.org](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html#kernel-density-estimatio). Have you tried it?

Comment: I do know about scikit, but I don't see anything about doing a KDE on a network